# Duda con plugin cordova-streaming-media en ionic

Tags: ionic, plugin, apache-cordova

Tengo una duda con el uso de este plugin.

Necesito usar este plugin para reproducir un vídeo y realizar una acción al terminar de verlo. El video sería una URL de Youtube....

¿Se puede usar para este fin?

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo. Este plugin no permite reproducir una URL de Youtube y por eso se cerraba.